# C# - How to load or refer to an specific version of dll based on the project?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, optimization, dll

I have a solution having 4 projects in that solution. 
Out of 4 project 1 project is common project and 3 are for different version

Now the problem is the service or methods which we are exposing are dependent of the version of the dll. I want to refer the dll according to the project which whose service is being hit at runtime so that i can optimize the code and put the common service or methods in the common code project.

Please suggest some way so that i can optimize the code and put those service contracts and method in common code base. I am unable to do so just because of version dependency.

Comment: Search about the concepts of AppDomains and Assembly Loading by Reflection, sure you will find a solution. I implemented many ways to determine the caller dll at runtime and used different methods for different dlls. I guess your problem is similar to mine.

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz..Thanxs for your suggestion..i really appreciate that but i think this is related to dynamic loading and i dont want to go for that just because it will end up in loading more than 100 of assemblies and might hamper the performance of the application.If you know any other way kindly suggest that

Comment: sure its fully related to dynamic loading thats why i mentioned "at runtime", i guess that i didn't get your question at all, maybe you could provide some skeletons or figures to make your question clearer for me and also other devs who possibly could answer.